# Best way to receive images uploaded by a user on Android app?

Tags: java, android, email

I'm working on an app that lets users submit orders, and also make custom orders where they upload an image. I then want to receive all this information by email. Initially, I was using JavaMail API with Gmail, but I heard that it can cause a blocking of the account due to "Suspicious Activity". Apparently a way around this is to use the Amazon SES SMTP server, but with that I cannot seem to find any documentation whatsoever on sending emails with attachments for Android (there is one but it's for general Java and it does not work on Android).

There must be a better way to to do this, I'm just not sure where to start looking. This is my first dev project (I'm in my 2nd year of computer science), so I'm pretty green with this stuff. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be so grateful. I'm open to learning new things, I'm just not even sure about what I need to learn in the first place for this.

Comment: use xampp server, store the image file in local directory and path in db field. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your email will be blocked if you are sending emails in huge amount like hundreds of email in a second if you are not sending email in such amount so don't worry about getting blocked and if you are sending in email in such amount then you can take external email service theirs a lot of marketing via email services i hope this might help